# Is the open ball compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The open ball $B(f,2)$ in $(C[0,1],\mathbb R)$, $d_{\infty}$), where $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ denotes the constant function $f(t)=5$ and $d_{\infty}(f,g)=max_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$

So I think the answer is that its not compact since the $B(f,2)$ is not closed and therefore according the the Heine-Borel theorem, the subset is not compact.

Is this right or have I messed up?

Comment: Neither of the statements "compact subspaces of a Hausdorff space are closed" and "compact subspaces fo a metric space are closed and bounded" is usually referred to as "Heine-Borel theorem". Heine-Borel theorem states that in $\Bbb R^n$ closed and bounded subsets are compact. Also, using that name for the forme would be confusing, seing it is standard to name the metric spaces where closed and bounded subsets are compact as having the "Heine-Borel property".

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The Heine-Borel theorem in general does not applies on subsets of functional spaces (such as $C([0,1])$) but is stated for $\mathbb R^n$. This is because in infinite dimensional spaces it can be that a closed and bounded set is not compact, and even that a compact set is not closed.

However, it is true that compact sets are closed in a Hausdorff space. And $C([0,1])$ is a Hausdorff space, since it is a metric space.

To see directly that the open ball $B(2)$ can't be compact, just take a sequence $\{B_n\}$ of balls, such that $B_n$ has radius $2-1/n$. Its union is the open ball $B(2)$, but you can't take any finite family of it which covers the open ball $B(2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I have it now :)

Comment: Couldn't hut to upvote the answer if it was helpful. If you think it answered your question then you should also click the green checkmark.